# Is there any difference between clear() and truncate(0) on a String?

Tags: string, rust, truncate, capacity

If `s` is a Rust `String`, is there any difference between calling `s.clear()` and `s.truncate(0)`? According to the documentation, neither will affect the capacity, and both will reduce the length to zero. Follow-up question, assuming they have the same identical result, which one is more idiomatic?

Answer (score 2):

According to the `std` source code, `clear` is implemented as `truncate(0)`, so they are identical, see

```rust
#[inline]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
pub fn clear(&mut self) {
    self.truncate(0)
}
```

As for the follow-up question, if `clear` exists my assumption would be that it is preferable to use it.

Comment: [This is mentioned on `Vec::truncate()` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.truncate): "Truncating when `len == 0` is equivalent to calling the `clear` method.".

Comment: Is `clear` considered more idiomatic than `truncate` or is it essentially irrelevant?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman good point, I have to admit that I came to it from `String` and I missed that note.